# Pity that my daughter lives 5000 kilometers away from me

Tags: translation

I want to translate this sentence into Italian:

Pity that my daughter lives 5000 kilometers away from me.

My attempt:

Peccato che mia figlia vive a 5000 chilometri da me.

Is my translation correct?

I would be glad if you answered my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In italiano si usa il congiuntivo, in questo caso, al posto del presente inglese:

> Peccato che mia figlia viva a 5000 chilometri da me

Inoltre, di solito, non si dice "da me" perché è sottinteso, quindi in italiano direi:

> Peccato che mia figlia viva a 5000 chilometri di distanza

---

In Italian we use the subjunctive in this case, instead of the English present tense:

> Peccato che mia figlia viva a 5000 chilometri da me

Furthermore, usually the "da me" (from me) is not translated because it is implied in the sentence:

> Peccato che mia figlia viva a 5000 chilometri di distanza

Comment: That's a good answer, but just as a side note: [it's always a good idea](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-allow-questions-answers-to-be-in-italian?lq=1) to (try to) answer in Italian to the questions, asked in Italian, and in English to the questions in English.

Comment: I'm sorry: normally I do. I added the translation, but please check my English.

Comment: Adding *di distanza* is optional (I wouldn't use it). Also *Peccato che mia figlia viva 5000 chilometri lontano*.

Comment: @egreg, I would prefer _a 5000 km di distanza_ over _5000 km lontano_. Maybe a regional difference? (I'm from Rome)

Answer (score 2):

Vorrei solo aggiungere una cosa: in italiano parlato spesso il congiuntivo viene erroneamente sostituito da altri tempi verbali. Se ti capitasse di sentire "Peccato che mia figlia viv**e** a 5000 km da me", o se ti capitasse di dirlo, non sarebbe un errore gravissimo (**Nel parlato e in un contesto informale, fra amici e parenti!**).

Ci sono contesti informali in cui è diventato quasi accettabile non usare il congiuntivo. In generale, però, non usarlo correttamente è ritenuto un segno di ignoranza. Ovviamente essendo tu non madrelingua non darai la stessa impressione